# Routing connection with nested menu in angular material fails

Tags: angular-material

Here, I am using angular material for designing application. I have created nested menu bar. Now i am trying to route each submenu option from menubar. For that i am using routerlink and routerActivateLink modules from RouterModule directive.
But routing is not proppogating as per the requirement.

here is my code for routing,

```
<mat-menu #adminmenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
      <button mat-menu-item><span>Account Maintenance</span></button>
      <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="room"><span>Room Maintenance</span></button>
            <mat-menu #room="matMenu">              
            <button mat-menu-item routerLink='addroom' routerLinkActive='active'><span>Add Room</span></button>
            <button mat-menu-item><span>View/Assigned Unclaimed Room</span></button>
            <button mat-menu-item><span>Modify/Update Room</span></button>
            <button mat-menu-item><span>Delete Room</span></button>
            <button mat-menu-item><span>Recover Deleted Room</span></button>
            </mat-menu>
      <button mat-menu-item>  </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

Here is my app.module.ts file,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyformComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    PageareaComponent,AddroomComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatMenuModule,  MatIconModule, MatCardModule, MatSidenavModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, MatInputModule, MatButtonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([  {path:'login',component:MyformComponent},
                            {path:'menu',component:MenuComponent},
                            {path:'addroom',component:AddroomComponent}])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Please suggest me solution how to create routing in this case.